# Doubts about series convergence/divergence and properties of compound functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Here are some questions about series and functions.
The task is to provide a counterexample for false statements and a proof for true statements (which are at most two).

[-> Questions in image format <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEKz0.jpg)

/Question in text format/

-(I) Let (a$_n$)$_n$$_\in$$ _\Bbb N$ and (b$_n$)$_n$$_\in$$ _\Bbb N$ be two sequences of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n)$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n)$ diverges to positive infinity. Then:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty sin(a_n^2)$ converges.
2. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(1+b_n^2)}$ converges.
3. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[]{|a_n|}(b_n^2)$ diverges.
4. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n$ converges.

-(II) Consider $f,g: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$. let $f$ be continuous and have an absolute minimum. Also, let $g$ be bounded and have an absolute minimum. Then:

1. $g\circ f$ is continuous.
2. $f\circ g$ is bounded.
3. $g\circ f$ has an absolute maximum.
4. $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question (I), all options are incorrect, so for contradicting options (1) and (4), take aₙ = (-1)ⁿ/√n, for option (2) take bₙ= 1/n, for option (3) take aₙ=1/n² and bₙ=1/n.
For question (II), option (a) is incorrect, take,$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
-1, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$. And take f(x)=x².
Option (b) is correct, since g is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, and since, f(x) is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ which is restricted on bounded domain g($\mathbb{R}$), so fg must bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.
option (c) is correct, since g is bounded on whole $\mathbb{R}$. So restricted g on f($\mathbb{R}$) must be bounded. So, g can take absolute maximum value.
Option (d) is incorrect, take f(x)=x²

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Can you clarify me how can you solve options 2, 3 and 4 (I) please.

Comment: For option (2), if I put bₙ=1/n, then the series become ∑n²/(1+n²), clearly as n tends to ∞, n²/(1+n²) tends to 1, so clearly this is a divergent series( since necessary condition for a convergent series ∑aₙ is lim aₙ=0).     For option (3), if I put bₙ=1/n and aₙ=1/n², then series becomes ∑1/n³ which is a convergent series.    For option (4) if I put aₙ=(-1)ⁿ/√n, then series becomes ∑1/√n , which is a divergent series.